# Rails 5 re-use before_validation code in multiple models with different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 application where users can enter currency values in different fields and different models.

Since I only serve one locale, I want users to be able to enter decimals using both . and , decimal separators and ignore any thousands separator.

For example, my users might enter: `1023.45` or `1023,45` but never `1.023,45`.

Simple solution that fits my use case: On specific decimal fields representing currency, replace `,` with `.` using `gsub(',', '.')`.

What is the best place to put this code? There are multiple models with differently named fields that need to use this code.

Preferably, I would use something like a custom validator that I create once and simply reference with 1 line from all models with the appropriate field. Very much like this example of a custom validator that checks whether an entered value is positive:

```
class PositiveValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value and BigDecimal.new(value).negative?
      record.errors[attribute] << 'is negative'
    end
  end
end
```

And then in the model reference it with:

```
validates :total, positive: true, allow_blank: true
```

However, this is ofcourse for validations, which shouldn't modify data. I tried to do this with concerns, but from the examples I have seen I should already know which fields are being transformed.

Do I really need to write in each model something like this:

```
before_validation lambda {self.total.gsub!(',', '.') if self.total}
```

or is there a more elegant Rails-like solution?

**edit:** again, note that field name 'total' might be different in each model

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom type-casting starting from Rails 4.2

```
class LocalFloat < ActiveRecord::Type::Float
  def cast_value(value)
    value = value.gsub(',', '.') if value.is_a? String
    super(value)
  end
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :total, LocalFloat.new
end

o = Order.new total: '5,5'
o.total # => 5.5
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. That works with a MySQL backed Decimal type as well? Or should I use a different type from Float then? Considering accuracy issues with storing currency

Comment: I slightly changed my answer @ChrisDekker, because you're right when point that values could be taken from the DB, so value could be a Float as well. See the implementation of superclass https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9cc8c6f3730df3d94c81a55be9ee1b7b4ffd29f6/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/float.rb

Comment: And this is a driver responsibility to convert Mysql decimal to ruby float